# How do I Concatenate Dataframes on the fly

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a list of dataframes using
`_dataframe_collection_ = {}`

I want to concatenate the data in these dataframes to build one big dataframe.
If I do

```
for i in range(_num_roles_):
     _dataframe_collection_[i] = pd.DataFrame(_roledata_json_[i])
     _concatenated_dataframe_ = pd.concat(_dataframe_collection_[i])
     print(_concatenated_dataframe_)
```

It fails on the pd.concat line with the following error

Error creating dataframe: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame".

How do I concatenate the data in  all the dataframes into one dataframe.

Comment: The most performant solution is to collect the dataframes into a list and then `pd.concat` at the very end.

Comment: `pd.concat(_dataframe_collection_[i])`...what are you concatenating the dataframe _to_? That line of code is basically saying sth like `x=1+` without a second term

Comment: My pd.concat statement has to be in the form 
_concatenated_dataframe_ = pd.concat(_dataframe_collection_0, _dataframe_collection_1, _dataframe_collection_2)
Need to figure out how to get it in that format

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to create the collection of dataframes that `pd.concat` is expecting:

```
_concatenated_dataframe = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(_roledata_json_[i]) for i in range(_num_roles_)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a list of DataFrames to concatenate in the `pd.concat()` method. It should look something like this `pd.concat([df1, df2])`. I'd prefer a list over a dictionary unless you need the keys for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

*dataframe_collection* = {} is not an empty list, it is an empty dictionary. Use square brackets instead of curly.

If roledata_json is a list of json strings, you will need to use pandas.read_json(). Hard to give better advice without know what that object is.

You shouldn't perform more than a single concat for performance reasons. concat creates a new object. concat takes a list of dataframes as its input as stated in other answers.